# Linear regression and matrix division in Julia

Tags: julia, linear-algebra

The well known formula for OLS is `(X'X)^(-1)X'y` where `X` is `nxK` and `y` is `nx1`.

One way to implement this in Julia is `(X'*X)\X'*y`.

But I found that `X\y` gives the almost same output up to the tiny computational error.

Do they always compute the same thing (as long as `n>k`)? If so, which one should I use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When `X` is square, there is a unique solution and [LU-factorization (with pivoting)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition) is a numerically-stable way to calculate this. That is the algorithm that backslash uses in this case.

When `X` is not square, which is the case in most regression problems, then there is no unique solution but there is a unique least square solution. The [QR factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) method for solving `Xβ = y` is a numerically stable method for generating the least square solution, and in this case `X\y` uses the QR-factorization and thus gives the OLS solution.

Notice the words numerically stable. While `(X'*X)\X'*y` will theoretically always give the same result as backslash, in practice backslash (with the correct factorization choice) will be more precise. This is because the factorization algorithms are implemented to be [numerically stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_stability). Because of the change for floating point errors to accumulate when doing `(X'*X)\X'*y`, it's not recommended that you use this form for any real numerical work.

Instead, `(X'*X)\X'*y` is somewhat equivalent to an SVD factorization which is the most nuemrically stable algorithm, but also the most expensive (in fact, it's basically writing out the [Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) which is how an [SVD factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular-value_decomposition) is used to solve a linear system). To directly do an SVD factorization using a pivoted SVD, do `svdfact(X) \ y` on v0.6 or `svd(X) \ y` on v0.7. Doing this directly is more stable than `(X'*X)\X'*y`. Note that `qrfact(X) \ y` or `qr(X) \ y` (v0.7) is for QR. [See the factorizations portion of the documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/linear-algebra/#man-linalg-factorizations-1) for more details on all of the choices.

Answer (score 6):

Following the documentation the result of `X\y` is (there notation `\(A, B)` is used not `X` and `y`):

> For rectangular A the result is the minimum-norm least squares solution

This is your case I guess as you assume `n>k` (so your matrix is not square). So you can safely use `X\y`. Actually it is better to use it than the standard formula as you will get a result even if rank of `X` is less than `min(n,k)`, whereas standard formula `(X'*X)^(-1)*X'*y` will fail or produce numerically unstable result if `X'*X` is nearly singular.

If `X` would be square (this is not your case) then we have a bit different rule in the documentation:

> For input matrices A and B, the result X is such that A*X == B when A is square

This means that the `\` algorithm would produce an error if your matrix were singular or produce numerically unstable results if the matrix were nearly singular (in practice most often `lu` function that is called internally for general dense matrices may throw `SingularException`).

If you want a catch-all solution (for square and non square matrices) then `qr(X, Val(true)) \ y` can be used.

Comment: A better catch-all is SVD, but it is more expensive than QR. There are matrices which are stable to solve under SVD but not QR. [This has an extended discussion on the numerical stability of the two algorithms](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall11/cos323/notes/cos323_f11_lecture09_svd.pdf).

Comment: Agreed, I use QR, because this is what Julia uses by default AFAIK.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: No, use the first one (the well-known one).

Long answer:

The linear regression model is `Xβ = y`, and it's easily to derive `β = X \ y`, which is your second method. However, in most time (when `X` is not invertible), this is wrong, since you cannot simply left multiply `X^-1`. The correct way is to solve `β = argmin{‖y - Xβ‖^2}` instead, which leads to the first method.

To show they are not always the same, simple construct a case where X is not invertible:

```
julia> X = rand(10, 10)
10×10 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.938995  0.32773   0.740556  0.300323   0.98479    0.48808    0.748006   0.798089  0.864154  0.869864
 0.973832  0.99791   0.271083  0.841392   0.743448   0.0951434  0.0144092  0.785267  0.690008  0.494994
 0.356408  0.312696  0.543927  0.951817   0.720187   0.434455   0.684884   0.72397   0.855516  0.120853
 0.849494  0.989129  0.165215  0.76009    0.0206378  0.259737   0.967129   0.733793  0.798215  0.252723
 0.364955  0.466796  0.227699  0.662857   0.259522   0.288773   0.691278   0.421251  0.593215  0.542583
 0.126439  0.574307  0.577152  0.664301   0.60941    0.742335   0.459951   0.516649  0.732796  0.990509
 0.430213  0.763126  0.737171  0.433884   0.85549    0.163837   0.997908   0.586575  0.257428  0.33239
 0.28398   0.162054  0.481452  0.903363   0.780502   0.994575   0.131594   0.191499  0.702596  0.0967979
 0.42463   0.142     0.705176  0.0481886  0.728082   0.709598   0.630134   0.139151  0.423227  0.942262
 0.197805  0.526095  0.562136  0.648896   0.805806   0.168869   0.200355   0.557305  0.69514   0.227137

julia> y = rand(10, 1)
10×1 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.7751785556478308
 0.24185992335144801
 0.5681904264574333
 0.9134364924569847
 0.20167825754443536
 0.5776727022413637
 0.05289808385359085
 0.5841180308242171
 0.2862768657856478
 0.45152080383822746

julia> ((X' * X) ^ -1) * X' * y
10×1 Array{Float64,2}:
 -0.3768345891121706
  0.5900885565174501
 -0.6326640292669291
 -1.3922334538787071
  0.06182039005215956
  1.0342060710792016
  0.045791973670925995
  0.7237081408801955
  1.4256831037950832
 -0.6750765481219443

julia> X \ y
10×1 Array{Float64,2}:
 -0.37683458911228906
  0.5900885565176254
 -0.6326640292676649
 -1.3922334538790346
  0.061820390052523294
  1.0342060710793235
  0.0457919736711274
  0.7237081408802206
  1.4256831037952566
 -0.6750765481220102

julia> X[2, :] = X[1, :]
10-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.9389947787349187
 0.3277301697101178
 0.7405555185711721
 0.30032257202572477
 0.9847899425069042
 0.48807977638742295
 0.7480061513093117
 0.79808859136911
 0.8641540973071822
 0.8698636291189576

julia> ((X' * X) ^ -1) * X' * y
10×1 Array{Float64,2}:
  0.7456524759867015
  0.06233042922132548
  2.5600126098899256
  0.3182206475232786
 -2.003080524452619
  0.272673133766017
 -0.8550165639656011
  0.40827327221785403
  0.2994419115664999
 -0.37876151249955264

julia> X \ y
10×1 Array{Float64,2}:
  3.852193379477664e15
 -2.097948470376586e15
  9.077766998701864e15
  5.112094484728637e15
 -5.798433818338726e15
 -2.0446050874148052e15
 -3.300267174800096e15
  2.990882423309131e14
 -4.214829360472345e15
  1.60123572911982e15
```

Comment: As I have noted in my answer `X\y` if `X` is not square actually gives a solution to `argmin{‖y - Xβ‖^2}` and is more efficient than the standard formula. If `X` is square (but this was not a question as there was assumption that `n>k`) and is rank deficient, as in your example, actually in theory both methods should throw an error. Your example only works because of numerical rounding errors. In principle `(X'*X)^(-1)` should throw an error for rank defficient matrix `X`.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. As @BogumiłKamiński states, when the matrix is not square then QR is used, and it gives the least-square solution, and thus `X\y` is the OLS solution. And backslash via QR is more numerically stable than the "traditional formula", and so backslash should always be the one that is used.